# FlexJson - Unable to Serialize Double[] array

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, flexjson

I have a simple user class with a Double[] variable for specifying a user's location.

```
@Document
public class User {
    private long id;
    private Double[] location;
}
```

This is the code that i have tried with to serialize my User object

```
new JSONSerializer()
           .transform(new ArrayTransformer(), Double[].class)
           .serialize(object));
```

But the location field won't get serialized, other fields are serialized though.. Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After much trying, I finally managed to make it work by explicitly including the field:

```
final String[] includedFields = {"location"}; 

new JSONSerializer()
                    .include(includedFields)
                    .serialize(object));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declaring the variable isn't enough since it's initialized to `null` by default.

Either set a value using setter method or initialize it with and empty array, for example:

```
private Double[] location = new Double[10];
```

Comment: Thanks Amila, I've tried adding that but it still wouldn't be serialized. I have checked inside my database and indeed the location data is there, just not getting serialized into json...